# Redirecting Subfolders But Not Folders

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I think I want to be able to do something like this

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(forewords)
```

but such that it matches /forewords/one, /forewords/two, /forewords/anything... without matching /forewords itself.

Is this easily done, or am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: Are you trying to say you would like to prevent access to `/forewords`?

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. I have a Laravel framework thing going on and I'm trying to find out if I can treat /forewords as a Laravel route but /forewords/anything as a different type of thing entirely. It may well not be a brilliant idea but just seeing if I can differentiate the various routes for now.